# How can I import data from an SQLite Database in Qlik Sense

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, qliksense, jupyterhub

I am coding on Jupyterhub's Jupyter Notebook to clean data and combine csv files before I add it to the SQLite database. Since I am using a work laptop, it is very restrictive which doesn't allow me to use MySQL or any other databases that need to be downloaded. SQLite was already part of the resources so I didn't have to download it so currently I am trying to make do with that. Now I am at a standstill as I can't figure out how to import my data into Qlik Sense.

But when it comes to Qlik Sense, I tried using ODBC to import the data but that requires me to download ODBC which I can't as my laptop won't let me. Is there any other way I go about doing this.

Comment: Is it possible to export the result into csv instead of inserting it into a DB?